# Updating navigation drawer after back press

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, fragment-backstack

I'm implementing an `Android` application with a `Navigation Drawer` and I have a problem with it.

I started from the template (Android app with navigation drawer) in Android studio and added a new section to it - Settings. When clicking the settings button the user is taken to a new Activity and the user can go BACK either by pressing the "up" button in the action bar (Which works perfectly) or by pressing the physical back button. That part doesn't work so good.

When pressing the "up" button and then opening the navigation bar, my home page is highlighted (selected). But when using the back button and opening the navigation drawer, the Settings item is selected, as if the user is viewing that page and not the home page.

So this is because the Navigation Drawer fragment isn't updated and I havent found any way to solve this problem. What I would like is for the Navigation Drawer to be recreated (Which is what I think happens when pressing the "up" button). Do you know how I can make this happen?

I started working on a solution based on this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
    new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            // Update your UI here.
        }
    });
```

But I don't know what to write there that will update the whole UI. (experimented with calling onCreate() but it's too ugly and can't be the right way).

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

The onBackStackChanged event isn't sent when pressing BACK from another activity. Only for fragments in the current actvity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.I used notifyDataSetChanged() in the ListView Adapter.

In getView() i used,

```
if(mListView.isItemChecked(position)) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_black_1000_12));
        }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the actionbar back button like this :

```
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
    this.finish();

//or

super.onBackPressed();

                break;

            }
            return true;

        }
```